# Non-angularJS page to angularJS page, and vice versa. Progressive conversion from non-angular to angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I'm currently weighing up whether I should make the jump to angularJS for our medium-sized web application. As the application grows and grows, it is becoming somewhat more difficult to maintain as a result of spaghetti jQuery and just general age. I've read and played a little with AngularJS, and from what I used it is pretty awesome.

The problem is that our web application is in constant use, and I cannot take it offline for any real period of time. Is it possible to progressively change pages from non-angular to angularJS? i.e. say, a page a week? (we have about 6 or 7 data rich pages).

Each page is usually isolated, and they don't usually rely on data from other pages apart from cookies and the occasional querystring.

Is this a sensible approach? Can AngularJS and non-AngularJS pages play nice together? Or would it be better to stick with JavaScript and jQuery?

EDIT: I realise this isn't a great question for SO, my bad. I forgot you aren't meant to ask for opinions :|

Comment: Duplicate it to a development environment and make the change there.

Comment: I work on the application constantly so it's already under constant development. I just want to know if it is a wise approach and whether non-angular and angular pages can play nice :)

Comment: It's not wise to to make this conversion on an in-use application.

Comment: We use an agile development method, with constant updates to the application every week or so. We aren't actually changing the one that is live every time.

Comment: It's definitely possible to update parts of the application to use angular while leaving the others alone, if that's what you're asking. I don't see much harm in that.

Comment: I second @KevinB opinion. Angular is not an "all or nothing" deal. Angular pages definitely "play nicely" with non-Angular pages.

Comment: and you could even have just a single section of a page handled with angular while the rest continues to work as-is.

Comment: I see. I thought that having angular directives in a page with ordinary javascript caused some problems, I'll have to look into that again! Thanks :D

Comment: You just have to make sure that nothing but angular interacts with that part of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this isn't a great question for S-O, because it's going to be somewhat opinion based, but I'll answer it anyway.

Yes, this can be done, but it's not a great idea. The benefits of Angular are most realized in single page application. Essentially all your code loads once, and then everything happens in the browser. Presumably your current web application is not an SPA, therefore you'll have to re-initialize/re-include all the required JS on every page that you want to be done in Angular. Angular's #-based routing might get messy as well depending on how your current application is set up.

You're much better off starting a parallel Angular application on a development server, point it to the same datasources and build it out over time until you can finally make the switch all at once. The end result will be much cleaner. You'll also won't be forced to make compromises against doing things the "angular way" just to keep everything in your current application functioning properly.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense about trying to do it all in one go. The problem is what kashesandr said "time and value". I don't think I could ever get authorisation from the boss to take time out to do this rather than actual updates (despite the fact that switching to angular would make this a lot better). I guess I could stress the point that it's just going to get worse the longer it isn't cleaned up and switched.

Comment: @MightyLampshade unfortunately, sometimes this job is about compromises. As I said, it can be done, but it's going to be harder and hopefully the process won't turn you off to Angular in general.

Answer (score 1):

Every approach is sensible ;) Depends on value and time.

I think you can create a basic structure in Angular and use existing code for each page (if it is really isolated enough). It shouldn't take a lot of time I believe.

And after that you may rewrite code page by page from spaghetti-style to something better.

Comment: You scored the two keywords in one answer: time and value :p I think I may give it a go, I may try doing one or two pages and seeing how they work.

Comment: I guess there should be a simple routing with dynamic js loading for each page for the first time.